# Mobile App Not Posting, Debugging Options

Tags: mobile

I've got myself logged into my WordPress install, self-hosted via a Namecheap installation. When I try to post, however, I get an error message that says "Post failed to upload." with no other information.

[image: Test post with a message at the bottom that says "Post failed to upload"]

I tried logging out of the app and back in, and I get this error message:

[image: an error message that says "Couldn't connect. Required XML-RPC methods are missing on the server.]

But I was able to log in once despite this, so I'm not sure if it's all related or a weird issue otherwise.

Comment: You'll need to try the [WordPress mobile app support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/forum/mobile/).